# add ListFragment with FragmentTransaction is not supported?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-intent, android-fragments

I have a `ListFragment`:

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment{
      ...
}
```

In order to use **Fragment** in my **Android 2.1 API 7** project, I use the  [support package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html). (Everything has configured for the support package)

In my host **Activity** looks like:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class FragmentNavActivity extends FragmentActivity {

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...

        FragmentManager fMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();  
        FragmentTransaction fTrans = fMgr.beginTransaction();

        MyListFragment myListFragment = new MyListFragment();

        fTrans.add(android.R.id.content, myListFragment).commit(); //problem here

        ...
    }

}
```

The problem is that the `FragmentTransaction` 's `.add(int, Fragment)` method accept arguments with the second one of type `Fragment`, however, I have `ListFragment` which is not acceptable by this method.

So, how to add `ListFragment` with `FragmentTransaction` ?

Comment: MyListFragment extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment?

Comment: Ovidiu, you are right, I have a wrong import for the ListFragment. Thanks! But the new problem is that after I import from v4.app.ListFragment instead of android.app.ListFragment, I can not use onAttach(Activity hostActivity) method in the ListFragment anymore, how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: @Leem.fin you should be able to use it. I suggest you list the code of the ListFragment with all imports to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is because you are importing `android.support.app.ListFragment`

Answer (score 0):

Try using nested fragments. In that way you can wrap your ListFragment inside a Fragment, which you can use in your FragmentTransaction

[Nested Fragments](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)